# I can't find the maximum value of P because of some problems in my solution.

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, substitution, uvw

Let a,b,c >0 satisfy :a+b+c=3. Find 
Max P, P= $\frac{2}{3+ab+bc+ca}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{abc}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}}$

I supposed that a=b=c. So that: $\sqrt[3]{\frac{abc}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}}\leq \frac{1}{3}(\frac{a}{1+a}+\frac{b}{1+b}+\frac{c}{1+c})$

Then, I proved that : $\frac{a}{1+a} \leq \frac{1}{4}(a-1)+\frac{1}{2}$ so $P\leq \frac{2}{3+ab+bc+ca}+\frac{1}{2}$. 
After that, I used $t=ab+bc+ca \in (0;3]$. I had $f(t)=\frac{2}{3+t}+\frac{1}{2}, t\in(0;3]$. Its derivative is $\frac{-2}{({3+t})^2}<0$. From that step i can't find the maximum value of P. Can you help me to find the problem in my solution? If you have another solutions of this exercise, please show the idea to me! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a=b=c=1$ we get $P=\frac{5}{6}.$

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that $$\frac{2u^2}{3u^2+3v^2}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{w^3}{w^3+3uv^2+4u^3}}\leq\frac{5}{6}.$$
But the expression $$\frac{2u^2}{3u^2+3v^2}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{w^3}{w^3+3uv^2+4u^3}}=\frac{2u^2}{3u^2+3v^2}+\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{3uv^2+4u^3}{w^3+3uv^2+4u^3}}$$ increases as a function of $w^3$, which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for a maximal value of $w^3$, which happens for equality case of two variables.
Let $b=a$ and $c=3-2a$, where $0<a<1.5$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$\frac{2}{3+a^2+2a(3-2a)}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^2(3-2a)}{(1+a)^2(4-2a)}}\leq\frac{5}{6}$$ or

$$(a-1)^2(2+67a+468a^2+1395a^3-78a^4-1371a^5+688a^6-91a^7)\geq0,$$ which is obviously true for any $a\in\left(0,\frac{3}{2}\right).$

Also, we can prove the last inequality by the following way.

We need to prove that 
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^2(3-2a)}{(1+a)^2(4-2a)}}\leq\frac{5}{6}-\frac{2}{3+a^2+2a(3-2a)}$$ or
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^2(3-2a)}{(1+a)^2(4-2a)}}\leq\frac{1+10a-5a^2}{6(1+2a-a^2)}$$ or $f(a)\geq0,$ where
$$f(a)=\ln(1+10a-5a^2)+\frac{2}{3}\ln(1+a)+\frac{1}{3}\ln(2-a)+\frac{1}{3}\ln2-$$
$$-\ln6-\ln(1+2a-a^2)-\frac{2}{3}\ln{a}-\frac{1}{3}\ln(3-2a).$$
Now, $$f'(a)=\frac{10-10a}{1+10a-5a^2}+\frac{2}{3(1+a)}-\frac{1}{3(2-a)}-\frac{2-2a}{1+2a-a^2}-\frac{2}{3a}+\frac{2}{3(3-2a)}=$$
$$=\frac{10(1-a)}{1+10a-5a^2}+\frac{1-a}{(1+a)(2-a)}-\frac{2(1-a)}{1+2a-a^2}+\frac{2(a-1)}{a(3-2a)}=$$
$$=(a-1)\left(\frac{2}{a(3-2a)}-\frac{1}{(1+a)(2-a)}-\frac{8}{(1+10a-5a^2)(1+2a-a^2)}\right).$$
Now, since 
$$\frac{2}{a(3-2a)}-\frac{1}{(1+a)(2-a)}-\frac{8}{(1+10a-5a^2)(1+2a-a^2)}>0$$
for any $a\in\left(0,\frac{3}{2}\right),$ we see that $a_{\min}=1$ and we are done!

By the way, after your first step and $b=c\rightarrow0^+$ we get that $P$ is closed to a value, which is greater than $\frac{5}{6}.$

Id est, your first step is not so good.

Comment: Can you explain more about this "But the expression $\frac{2u^{2}}{3u^{2}+3v^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{w^{3}}{w^{3}+3uv^{2}+4u^{3}}}$ increases as a function of $w^{3}$, which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for a maximal value of $w^{3}$, which happens for equality case of two variables."

Comment: How can you form this inequality $(a-1)^{2}(2+67a+468a^{2}+1395a^{3}-78a^{4}-1371a^{5}+686a^{6}-91a^{7})$? I find it difficult to do this.

Comment: @Trần Tuấn I did not understand your last question. You meant, how I got this inequality or how to prove it? Also, I'll explain why the expression is increases. Say please if it's clear and ask one question. I am ready to explain all steps.

Comment: I meant that how you got that inequality. Please, make it clearly for me..

Comment: Please tell me why the expression increases as a function of $w^{3}$ and we can prove the inequality for a maximal value of $w^{3}$. This method is quite strange to me

Comment: @Trần Tuấn $w^3+3uv^2+4u^3$ increases as function of $w^3$. Thus, $\frac{3u^2+4u^3}{w^3+3uv^2+4u^3}$ decreases, which says $-\frac{3u^2+4u^3}{w^3+3uv^2+4u^3}$ increases and $1-\frac{3u^2+4u^3}{w^3+3uv^2+4u^3}$ increases as a function of $w^3$. Also, about $uvw$ see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

Comment: I'm sorry to make you misunderstand my problem. I want to know why the inequality for a maximal value of $w^{3}$ can be proved when $f(w^{3})$ increases... If we meet a problem whose $f(w^{3})$ decreases, what will happen??

Comment: @Trần Tuấn Let $k$ be a maximal value of $w^3$. Thus, $w^3\leq k$ and since $f$ increases, we obtain: $f(w^3)\leq f(k).$ Thus, it's enough to prove that $f(k)\leq\frac{5}{6}.$ Thus, it's enough to prove our inequality for maximal value of $w^3$. If $f$ decreases it does not help.